# Fetching Parameter from URL into HTML Page which have special character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, github, github-pages

I wanted to create a custom website where some parameters will be fetched from URL and displayed inside html.

Let the link be: [https://www.example.com?abc=anything&def=hello world&ghi=father & son](https://www.example.com?abc=anything&def=hello%20world&ghi=father%20&%20son)

The values are fetched from an excel sheet, so I cannot edit the spaces, etc.

I used jQuery for the same.

```
function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&&');
for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
{
    var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
    if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
    {
        return sParameterName[1];
    }
}
}
var abc = GetURLParameter('abc');
```

The `&&` is due to the fact that some of my parameter may contain & like `A & B Product`

And I also have the problem that, the link will be created like above with spaces, so need to parse that back to normal text as well.

And to display the same, I am using:

```
<p>document.write(abc)</p>
```

I want to fetch data in URL somehow which will work with Github Hosting and display it in HTML without any HTML Special Character Problem. Github don't support PHP, else this was a piece of cake.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To make variables URL safe you can encode them using `encodeURI()`. For example:

```
let a = 'A & B Product';
console.log(encodeURI(a));
// will output: `A%20&%20B%20Product`
```

And then to decode on the other side:

```
console.log(decodeURI(a));
// will output `A & B Product`
```

Comment: I cannot do that because as I said, I would be exporting the data from an excel sheet directly to a third party mail server to send a message which will contain the link. I can only play with the link and the website content.